# Github: How to get local to reflect a remote branch

Tags: git, github

I made changes that I don't want to continue with, so I want my branch, rebecca_dev to be updated to match the upstream dev branch.
I then want those changes to rebecca_dev to be reflected locally.

I've tried:

```
git checkout rebecca_dev
git fetch dev
git merge dev
Already up to date.
```

When I check the online repo on Github, I expect the coding documents locally, and in the rebecca_dev remote, to match those in dev, but this is not the case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you're making changes locally and expecting the changes to be seen on the remote branch.

So let's go line by line

`git checkout rebecca_dev`: This will checkout the **rebecca_dev** branch locally.
`git fetch dev`: Will fetch the remote dev changes, this is reflected locally in the **origin/dev** branch. (Assuming the remote is referred by **origin**). This **will not**  update the local **dev** branch.
`git merge dev`: So you're merging the local **dev** branch to the local **rebecca_dev** branch. Do note you don't have the latest **remote dev** changes on the local **dev** branch.

What you'd want to do instead:

```
git checkout rebecca_dev
git fetch dev
git merge origin/dev
git push
```

The last step pushes the local changes to the remote branch to update it too.

Comment: This did not work, at least not as I expected. The code document in my local directory still does not match dev.

Comment: Hello @RebeccaEliscu could you show the output for the following commands; `git log --oneline dev` `git log --oneline rebecca_dev` & `git log --oneline origin/dev`

Comment: But why `git fetch`? This doesn‘t download the changes to local, just inform about the changes. So try `git pull`, this would download all changes to local so you can merge it

Comment: I'm confused by this line: "git fetch dev: Will fetch the remote dev changes, this is reflected locally in the origin/dev branch... This will not update the local dev branch". This seems contradictory to me. What exactly does git fetch dev, do, then? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @RebeccaEliscu it fetches the changes from remote, but doesn't apply them to the local branches. You can think of `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git am` (`git am` is to apply and merge)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

This happens, when the local branch **isn‘t** *up to date* with the remote branch. So you must first bring your local branch *up to date* with `git pull` in this branch.

So first checkout dev and then `git pull` there. Now your local `dev` branch is *up to date* with the remote `dev` branch.

Then you will be able to `git merge` the new changes from `dev` into your `rebecca_dev` branch.

All steps summarized:

```
git checkout dev
git pull
git checkout rebecca_dev
git merge dev
```

Comment: This didn't quite do what I wanted. I also tried "git checkout rebecca_dev,
git pull dev,
git merge origin/dev,
git push", and this worked. Can you explain how what you suggest here is different? Sorry, very new to git.

Comment: Sorry, this DID seem to work (can't edit my previous comment). Still unsure about why both this, and what I mentioned in the previous comment worked, however.

Comment: In both ways, the steps are very similar: `git checkout rebecca_dev` and then `git pull dev` is the same as `git checkout dev`, `git pull` and `git checkout rebecca_dev`. The last command `git merge dev` merge the local branch dev and `git merge origin/dev` merge from the remote branch dev, so `git pull dev`  is actually not necessary, then you merge from remote! I hope now it is clearer :)!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, this is extremely helpful -- thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I hope I could fix your problem with my answer and comment!